# Выход из приложения или переход на стартовый фрагмент кнопкой "назад"

Tags: java, android

Есть драйвер лайяут с фрагментами, при старте приложения запускается первый фрагмент, через драйвер лайяут можно переходить на разные фрагменты. Вопрос - как сделать, что-бы при нажатии кнопки "назад" на первом стартовом фрагменте приложение закрывалось, а на других фрагментах при нажатии на кнопку "назад", открывался стартовый фрагмент?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это также можно сделать переопределив метод активити `onBackPressed()` примерно так:

```
//переменная хранящая позицию текущего отображаемого фрагмента. Изначально - 0
//т.е. первый фрагмент. При замене фрагментов надо менять это число
//не забываем сохранять это значение при пересоздании активити
int currentPositionOfFragment = 0;

@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    Log.e("LOG", "onBackPressed");
    if(currentPositionOfFragment != 0)
    { 
        //отображается не первый фрагмент, значит отображаем его
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        //отображается первый фрагмент, значит выходим из приложения
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

нашел ответ тут [ссылка на ответ](http://ru.androids.help/q5651), у себя реализовал так:

стартовый фрагмент:

```
 @Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    getView().requestFocus();
    getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    getActivity().finish();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

любой другой фрагмент:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    getView().requestFocus();
    getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    FragmentFirst fragmentFirst = new FragmentFirst();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fragmentFirst);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    // помечаем в драйвере первый фрагмент
                    MainActivity.navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```